# In SwiftUI, for iPad device specifically, how to change the width for a Table?

Tags: swiftui, ipad

I have folllowing code to show a Table in iPad

```
    Table(users) {
        TableColumn("Employee ID") { user in
            Text(user.employeeId)
        }
        .width(ideal: 30.0)
                 
        TableColumn("Name") { user in
            Text(user.displayName)
        }
        .width(ideal: 30.0)
                
        TableColumn("Email") { user in
            Text(user.email)
        }
        .width(ideal: 150.0)
                
        TableColumn("On Board") { user in
            Text(DateFmt.shortDate.string(from: user.onboardDate))
        }
        .width(ideal: 40.0)
    }
```

It works perfect except the width() doesn't work at all. No matter what numbers I put in. I also tried `min` or `max`, no effects.

It's obvious I need wider column for a property like email, but the column width seems always divided evenly between columns.

How to change the width for a Table for iPad specifically? (In macOS, width() above works, I know, I've tried)

Or if width() doesn't work for iOS (my guess is that the column width cannot be changed by user fingers anyway), is there some way to make certain column larger? For example, email property here needs larger space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS/iPadOS you have to

1. put your table inside horizontally scrollable Scroll view , Since only macOS provide horizontal scroll fro table by default.
2. And then set the width of the frame of your table ; the total of all the column sizes.

```swift
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            Table(users) {
                    TableColumn("Employee ID") { user in
                        Text(user.employeeId)
                    }
                    .width(30.0)
                             
                    TableColumn("Name") { user in
                        Text(user.displayName)
                    }
                    .width(30.0)
                            
                    TableColumn("Email") { user in
                        Text(user.email)
                    }
                    .width(150.0)
                            
                    TableColumn("On Board") { user in
                        Text(DateFmt.shortDate.string(from: user.onboardDate))
                    }
                    .width(40.0)
                }
            .frame(width: 250) //<- 30+30+150+40
        }
```

Comment: `ideal` doesn't work